# C# Attach content of string to regex pattern

Tags: regex

Is it possible to attach one of a String contents to regex pattern?
Something like this, where it's need to output a Page12 from ramPage1220

```
String a="12"
String rp=@"[A-Z]+[a-z]+"+a
String a1="ramPage1220"

foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(a1,rp))
{
Console.WriteLine(m.NextMatch().ToString())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not too sure about the regex you have used. But it is possible to attach one of the string content to the pattern, it will work fine. I just tested this on .NET Fiddler - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1wuj7m

and your regex should change to this

```
String rp=@"[a-zA-Z]+"+a;
```

Tested that on RegExr - http://www.regexr.com/38svb